# How to integrate an expression with a squared differential?

Tags: integration, physics

Most likely this is a really easy question, but I forgot how to do it. It is also related to physics, but a mathematical question.

In physics the distance $x$ an object travels in some time $t$ given a gravitational field $g$ is

$$x=\frac{1}{2}g\,t^2$$

with $g$ depending on the current distance to a mass $M$

$$g(x) = \frac{GM}{x^2}$$

As the object moves a distance $\Delta x$ in some time $\Delta t$ I get:

$$\Delta x=\frac{1}{2}g\,\Delta t^2$$

and so

$$dx=\frac{1}{2}g\,(dt)^2$$

and finally

$$dx=\frac{1}{2}\frac{GM}{x^2}\,(dt)^2$$

Multiplying by $x^2$ I get

$$dx\,x^2=\frac{1}{2} G\,M\,(dt)^2$$

Easy to integrate the LHS, but how to integrate the RHS (with the differential squared)? Substitute it somehow? How to proceed?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find? The total distance, or something else? Also $d(t^2)=2t \ dt$

Comment: I have $(dt)^2$, I updated the question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: That formula for the distance only applies for constant gravitational fields. If it's not constant, you need to use newton's second law to set up the differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

Puttign aside the physics, what you are doing is mathematically not correct. Indeed, we have that

$$\dfrac{x(t+h)-x(t)}{h} = \dfrac{GM}{2hx(t+h)^2}(t+h)^2-\dfrac{GM}{2hx(t)^2}t^2.$$

Equivalently,

$$\dfrac{x(t+h)-x(t)}{h} = \dfrac{GM}{2hx(t+h)^2}(t^2+2th+h^2)-\dfrac{GM}{2hx(t)^2}t^2.$$

Then, letting $h\to0$ yields $x(t+h)\to x(t)$ and

$$x'(t) = \dfrac{GM}{2x(t)^2}2t=\dfrac{GM}{x(t)^2}t.$$

Or, in other words,

$$dx=\dfrac{GM}{x^2}tdt.$$